# Detect windows logout in Python

Tags: python, winapi

How can I detect, or be notified, when windows is logging out in python?

Edit:
Martin v. Löwis' answer is good, and works for a full logout but it does not work for a 'fast user switching' event like pressing win+L which is what I really need it for.

Edit: im not using a gui this is running as a service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect fast user switching events using the Terminal Services API, which you can access from Python using the `win32ts` module from [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). In a GUI application, call [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841.aspx) to receive notification messages, [WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383847.aspx) to stop receiving notifications, and handle the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828.aspx) message in your window procedure.

If you're writing a Windows service in Python, use the [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685058.aspx) function to detect fast user switching events. This is available in the pywin32 library as the `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` function in the `servicemanager` module. In your [handler function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241.aspx), look for the `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notification. See also the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828.aspx) documentation for details of the specific notification codes.

There's some more detail in [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-January/006736.html) from the python-win32 mailing list, which may be useful.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In a console application, you can use win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler and look for CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT. In a GUI application, you need a window open and wait for the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message. How precisely that works (and if it works at all) depends on your GUI library.

Comment: As I know, win32api can be used in wxpython apps too. Anyway, I can't reach the top of abilities of this module (win32)...

Comment: This seems to mostly work however it does not get a 'fast user switching' even like if you hit win+l, any ideas there?